# How to create a partition in Azure SQL Table

Tags: azure-sql-database, partitioning

I am going to create a SQL tables in Azure SQL database, and I want to create a partition of table, but I don't know how to do that, can any one show me some demo example or query to perform this. I am using SQL management studio to connect my Azure db.

Comment: This is my search result:https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3494/azure-sql-database--table-partitioning/

Answer (score 3):

We take advantage of partitioning SQL Azure tables. We use it so we can rapidly truncate the oldest partitions of data.

We have a great blog post that walks through step by step how to do it:
https://stackify.com/how-to-partition-tables-in-azure-sql/

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old post but this may help:

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3494/azure-sql-database--table-partitioning/

I'm not sure what your use case is but Elastic Database Tools for Azure SQL Database allow you to implement sharding if you are partitioning the table because of its size.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-elastic-scale-introduction