# How come I have no option to Create Partition?

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I have no option to Create Partition on my table.

I thought maybe I had to create a filegroup first, but I have no option for that either under the database properties.

What am I missing?

*This is an Azure database.

[image]

Comment: This https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/3494/azure-sql-database--table-partitioning/ appears to indicate it's supported in Azure SQL. Maybe just not in the SSMS GUI

Comment: Does this help? [How to create a partition in Azure SQL Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38504615/how-to-create-a-partition-in-azure-sql-table)

Comment: On the Web page [How much research effort is expected of Stack Overflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) the following is written: ___Asking a question on Stack Overflow should be the last step in your process for finding an answer___ Did you research before posting your question?

Comment: @Abra Of course I researched thoroughly before posting. Yes, there are plenty of documents describing how to partition Azure in SQL, but none of them show the utilization of the built in partition wizard that does not include using the "Create Partition" option that is not included. I just want to use the wizard. My question is why can't I.

Comment: @user3846899 The reason is that the full SSMS UI support for Azure SQL database is not support. Many people have post feedback for this problem, but still no solutions. If my answer is helpful for you, hope you can mark it as answer. This can be beneficial to other community members. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

We can create partition on table with T-sql like comments mentioned.

As you know, SSMS UI: Create Partition works well with local SQL Server, no option for Azure SQL Database.

Actually, not only the Create Partition option, there many options not support for Azure SQL database. Most documents only say the feature is supported in Azure SQL database with no details.

You could reference this blog:[No UI dialogs in MS Azure / SQL Server Management Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26978549/no-ui-dialogs-in-ms-azure-sql-server-management-studio).

The reason is that SSMS do not have the full SSMS Support for Azure SQL database.

A lot of people complained about this in the SQL database feedback:

[How can we improve Azure SQL Database?Full Management Studio Support](https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217321-sql-database/suggestions/476408-full-management-studio-support)

Such as:

- "Graham Plowman commented  ·  January 23, 2019 17:01

  The regular version of SSMS has a UI around all the security and user
  management options (and many others), making them a breeze to use.

  When SSMS is connected to a SQL Azure database, all this UI
  functionality is gone, replaced by bombing out to screens where one
  has to type in SQL commands!!

  Whatever next ? This was how we used to manage SQL server way back in
  the 1990's with version 4.3 before SSMS became a serious tool!!

  Kindly add the UI so it is the same as regular SQL installations.
  Bombing out to SQL is a highly backward step."

There is still no solution for now.

Hope this helps.